# Изменение адреса страницы

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите, как через `.htaccess` изменить c `profile?id=&session[id];` на что-нибудь другое. Для примера просто `profile1` или `idn1`. Если есть какой-нибудь пример, скиньте пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /profile?id=&session[id] /profile1 [R=301,L]
```